# pl/sql slower than cursor

Tags: sql, oracle

I am converting a SQL Server system to run on Oracle (11g). The system has all been set up, data loaded, etc. The amount of data is quite large (160m records in tables, etc.). The server is an HP DL380 with 1tb raid 1+0 and 96gb memory.

In testing, I find the inexplicable, in that a SQL insert statement using 3-4 tables takes over 90 minutes to run, whereas the same logic using cursors takes about 3 minutes!

This takes about 8 minutes for cursors and 2-3 minutes for SQL on SQL Server (which is what I expect).

In other words Oracle SQL is 30-50 times slower than a cursor. It gives me the impression that the Oracle system is very fast at OLTP (individual record inserts) but really slow at manipulating larger tables in SQL.

I am certain this is not the usual case, and so am asking, are there any Oracle 'parameters' that need to be adjusted?

Below is an example of the SQL used:

```
INSERT INTO TMP_TXN ......
SELECT .......
  FROM TXN (160m rows), CUSTOMERS (1m rows), PRODUCTS (1k rows)
 WHERE TXN.TXN_DATE = p_date 
   AND TXN.TXN_AMOUNT > 0 
   AND TXN.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID 
   AND PRODUCTS.PRODTYPE_ID IN ('1', '12', '13');
   AND TXN.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID 
   AND CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_STATUS LIKE 'A%'
```

and

```
FOR item IN (SELECT .....
              FROM TXN (160m rows), CUSTOMERS (1m rows), PRODUCTS (1k rows)
              WHERE TXN.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID
                AND CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_STATUS LIKE 'A%'
                AND TXN.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID
                AND PRODUCTS.PRODTYPE_ID IN ('1', '12', '13')
                AND TXN.TXN_DATE = p_date
                AND TXN.TXN_AMOUNT > 0
              ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID);
  LOOP         
     IF item.customer_id <> customer_id_old THEN
     etc.
```

The indexes (on TXN) are for CUSTOMER_ID and TXN_DATE. The indexes on TMP_TXN are for CUSTOMER_ID (and a couple of others not required by this script).

Please don't get hung up about this example SQL. It is one of literally hundreds and EVERY SINGLE ONE runs slow but when using cursors, the scripts run 10-50 times faster. When running the SQL, I look at the resource monitor and see that the Data tablespace is hardly touched (1mb/sec) whereas the UNDO / REDO tablespaces are 3-50mb/sec. The REDO log files were resized to 10gb as they were previously switching about every 1-2 seconds!

As this is totally wrong, my guess is that there is some Oracle setup problem that I have missed. Any ideas for this incredibly slooooow performance from Oracle SQL?

Comment: The system has buffers cleared for each run, etc. So no caching difference.

Comment: looking at performance monitor when running the SQL showed disk data throughput of 1mb/sec, whereas the cursors ran at 70mb/sec.

Comment: There is no magic `set fast=true` parameter.  Good performance is born from understanding of Oracle.  You are right to think that your results are not natural and that you are missing something.  Did you create reasonable indexes on all these tables to support these queries?  Did you gather statistics?

Comment: Hi. Yes, the tables have appropriate indexes and stats have been calculated.

Comment: Can you show the execution plan for the insert as it runs on SQL Server and as it runs on Oracle?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the indexes you have defined on each of your tables and the execution plans generated for both the SELECT and INSERT. Also - what indexes do you have on TMP_TXN? Thanks.

Comment: The indexes (on TXN) are for CUSTOMER_ID and TXN_DATE.

As for execution plans, I can generate them, but I can't find a way to extract this in any readable form (from SQL Developer).

Comment: Please don't get hung up about this example SQL. It is one of literally hundreds and EVERY SINGLE ONE runs slow but when using cursors, the scripts run 10-50 times faster.

When running the SQL, I look at the resource monitor and see that the Data tablespace is hardly touched (1mb/sec) whereas the UNDO / REDO tablspaces are 3-5mb/sec. The REDO log files were resized to 10gb as they were previously switching about every 1-2 seconds!

Comment: try https://dba.stackexchange.com/ this isn't a programming question

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have moved this to the dba stream.

Comment: What about an index On txn(txn_date, productid, amount ). How many of the 160m rows in txn are actually selected from the query. A single insert should be quicker due to no context switching but as per other suggestion use the append hint. Customers also needs an index on status if the like 'A%' is selective

Comment: There is an index in txn for date. I tried compound indexes but these didn't seem to make any difference. In any case the select is the same for both queries (SQL and cursor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just doing some large batch operations, which need no live backup by Oracle, you can think about using Direct Load Insert, which will skip writing REDO.

```
INSERT /*+ append nologging */ INTO TMP_TXN ...
SELECT ...
```

Append issues to write behind the "high watermark" which is the current end of your table's position in the tablespace instead of searching for an empty block big enough for inserting a new row. Depending on your database settings it is necessary to make Direct Load work, [more info here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nologging_append.htm). It's not mandatory to define it in the table's DDL, as you probably won't need it in every action.

Judging by the `p_date` Parameter it looks like you use both inside a PL/SQL procedure? Be aware that switching between plsql engine and sql engine [has an impact on the performance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html). A `FOR` statement will fetch some hundred rows before processing them, giving some benefit, but Inserting will still be row-by-row.

The given examples seem to differ between n Inserts per Customer and only 1 Insert, as well as no supportive index on `CUSTOMERS`, but you asked not to concentrate on that.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. All scripts are part of stored procedures. 
I have tried table nologging and /*+ append */.  This did make things faster - but not by much. The SQL was still much slower than the cursor loop.
Both statements produce the same results (only part shown).
Also, there are appropriate indexes on all tables.